# MongoDB parseError when using limit and sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parsing, sorting, limit

I'm just trying to use sort and limit in mongoDB, but I get a parseError, only if the limit I enter is to big.

```
handCollection = db.collection('hands');
handCollection.count(function(err,res){numHands=res;console.log(numHands)}) //logs 12542

limit=10000
query= query.sort({gameNum:-1}).limit(limit)

query.toArray(function(er,hands){
    if (er)
        throw er
    console.log('Hands Sent:'+hands.length)
    res.send(JSON.stringify(hands));
)};
```

This code works when setting limit to 10000, but when I set limit=12000, I'll get the following error:

```
Error: parseError occured                                                                      
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\poker-tell\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connec 
tion\connection_pool.js:182:34)                                                                
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)                                                     
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\poker-tell\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\conn 
ection\connection.js:389:20)                                                                   
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)                                              
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)                                         
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)                                              
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)                                              
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)                                                
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)                                            
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

What does that mean and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you build index on the field "gameNum"? AFAIK in the build in mongo command line when you try to sort by a field without index and try to get a large number of records you'll get an error. Don't know if this is the case in nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If limit quantity is the key reason why your query fails, then I suggest you should make sure if you have an index on the specified sort field (in your case it's "gameNum"). If not, build an index:

```
db.colname.ensureIndex({gameNum: 1})
```

you can read the [document about sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) here, which tells you:

> Note For in-memory sorts that do not use an index, the sort()
>   operation is significantly slower. The sort() operation will abort
>   when it uses 32 megabytes of memory.

Besides, you should also consider @Neil Lunn's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at making sure you have the latest driver as the first thing you do, just to make sure you are not picking up a problem that may have been addressed.

The main point I see is that you are accessing a lot of records and using [toArray()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray), which is going to do exactly what is says and just pull all the documents into an array.

I would try changing that call to use [each()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each) and push onto your array within the callback. At least that way if there is something that is causing this to trip up on a specific document, you'll have a better idea of where that is happening.

Consider your use case as well, 10,000 documents is a lot to return to a client. You may need it, but then again you may not if there is a better way to achieve what you want.